About controllable and observable discrete-time LTI systems
Consider the discrete-time LTI system with the following state-space representation:
\begin{align}
    {x}_{k+1}&={A} {x}_k+{B} {u}_k  &;{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, {B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \\ 
    {y}_k&={C} {x}_k  &;{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n} 
\end{align}
where \$ {x}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n \$ is the state, \$ {u}_k \in \mathbb{R}^m \$ is the control input and \$ {y}_k \in \mathbb{R}^p \$ is the measured output.
Suppose, this system is controllable and observable, also assume that \$\mathrm{N}=\mathrm{n}\$. So the controllability matrix \$B_N\$ and the observability matrix \$O_N\$, which are constructed as follows, are of rank \$n\$.
\$\$
\begin{aligned}
& B_N=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
A^{N-1} B & \cdots & A B & B
\end{array}\right] \\
& O_N=\left[\begin{array}{c}
C \\
C A \\
\vdots \\
C A^{N-1}
\end{array}\right] \\
\end{aligned}
\$\$
In this paper, it’s shown that \$x_k\$ can be calculated using the system’s previous inputs and outputs as follows:
\begin{equation}
     x_k=M\begin{bmatrix}
                     u_N(k-N) \\
                     y_N(k-N) 
                   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
  u_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
             u_{k-N}^T & u_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & u_{k-1}^T 
           \end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  y_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
             y_{k-N}^T & y_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & y_{k-1}^T 
           \end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
\$\$
\begin{aligned}
& T_N=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\
C B & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
C A B & C B & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
C A^{N-2} B & \cdots & \cdots & C B & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
& O_N^{+}=\left(O_N^T O_N\right)^{-1} O_N^T \\
& M=\left[B_N-A^N O_N^{+} T_N \quad A^N O_N^{+}\right] \\
&
\end{aligned}
\$\$
I have simulated several controllable and observable systems and observed that \$ M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (m+p)n}\$ has rank \$n\$ for these systems. I am now eager to prove this in general:
"For any controllable and observable discrete-time LTI system, prove that the rank of \$M\$ is \$n\$ ."
As a first step, I attempted to prove this for Single Input Single Output (SISO) systems where \$m=p=1\$. Under this assumption, the matrix \$O_N\$   is a square, invertible matrix, and the matrix  \$B_{N}^{-1}AB_N\$ is a companion matrix. it appears that \$M\$   failing to have full rank necessarily implies that the system cannot be controllable, as there would be elements \$x\$  of the state space that lie outside the column space of \$M\$  and thus cannot be attained. Nevertheless, I couldn't complete the proof and any help would be appreciated

You can probably prove this using the PBH test, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma, and properties of matrix ranks. But I don't think this is the appropriate StackExchange, as this problem is "just" linear algebra and would be better suited to Math.SE.

@jDAQ , this question is also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4946262/1283704
